# Gaussian Copula Function

Tags: probability, correlation

I have a question that I believe I know the answer to, but I would like to double check.

Is it possible to use a copula function to calculate the joint probability of three or more variables?

I'm asking because on this PDF https://www.math.ust.hk/~maykwok/courses/Dyn_Cred_Models/Topic2.pdf 
on page 21, at the bottom it says:

"Knowing the joint distribution of random variables allows us to
derive the marginal distributions and the correlation structure
among the random variables but not vice versa."

And I'm trying to use the correlation coefficients and the probabilities of three events to calculate the joint probability of them.

I'm sorry if this question is obvious.

Thanks!